# How to find an organization identifier in a price class

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-ebs, oracle-apps, oracle-bi

I am trying to extract data of price classes and corresponding inventory organizations. Price class tables are QP_PRICE_LIST_ITEMS, QP_MATRIX_RULES, etc. 
Because I am extracting item by item, so the only thing Ive got to start with is the item code and the org code however qp_price_list_items doesn't have an org code. How do I find an inventory organization in QP tables?

Comment: Table structures, sample data and expected output, please

Answer (score 1):

This question relates to [Oracle Supply Chain Management](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/supply-chain-management/18b/oedsc/QP-tables.html).

The documentation for [QP_PRICE_LIST_ITEMS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/supply-chain-management/18b/oedsc/QP_PRICE_LIST_ITEMS-tbl.html) lists a foreign key on QP_PRICE_LISTS_ALL_B.PRICE_LIST_ID. And lo! The description of [that table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/supply-chain-management/18b/oedsc/QP_PRICE_LISTS_ALL_B-tbl.html) says it has a column ORG_ID which *"[i]ndicates the identifier of the business unit associated to the row."*

Comment: That ORG_ID is different to what I want - i am wondering if there is any other fields that do this. Thanks though.